# PhpStorm / WebStorm - Hotkey to Collapse/Fold Code Comments Matching Criteria

Tags: phpstorm, comments, webstorm

When I try to understand someone elses code, I'll comment out things out, break it, and write some notes in my own little island comment block like this:

```
// ----------------------------------
// KJ NOTES:
// Searches for screenreader text, which is metadata
// E.preventdefault() is to prevent click from firing off (on the link that its on)
// IMPORTANT `toggleClass` which is a jQuery function to add submenu controls ★
//
// Dropdown symbol was defined above, its just a class. We modify the text to `-`
// .text is jQuery
// ----------------------------------

container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
    var _this = $( this ),
        screenReaderSpan = _this.find( '.screen-reader-text' );
        dropdownSymbol = _this.find('.dropdown-symbol');
        dropdownSymbol.text(dropdownSymbol.text() === '-' ? '+' : '-');

    e.preventDefault();
    _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' ); //★ This is what controls submenus from appearing
```

A lot of my comments are redundant and pointless, since most of the code is self-explanatory. But it helps me understand what's going on.

**Is there a way for PhpStorm to recognize all my island code comments matching a specific criteria? So I can press a hotkey to collapse them all.**

From this:

```
    // ----------------------------------
    // KJ NOTES
    // ....comments here
    // ----------------------------------
```

to this:

```
    // ... KJ NOTES
```

or the default

```
    // ...
```

by pressing a single hotkey. Possibly some controls to have it work on that particular file, and across the entire repo as well.

Comment: Nope. The only stuff that exists for comments folding is: 1) collapse/expand Doc-comments (e.g. PHPDoc or similar) or 2) custom folding regions. There is no functionality to recognize someone else's comment from yours (maybe there is some custom plugin for that but I'm not aware of such).

Comment: okay thanks i figured it didn't exist but I wanted to make sure

Comment: The best **I** may suggest here is to place your comments into custom-folding regions (that are quite rarely used anyway) and work on that basis. This though means adding extra 2 lines of comments: one for opening marker and one for closing; not sure about "collapse on demand" for them -- but option exist for "Default code folding" .. so re-opening teh file should do the trick. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/folding-code-elements.html